# Accessing router login page

Tags: router, captive-portal

I have a router that has a captive portal enabled.

When I enter the router IP address, I go directly to the captive portal webpage. How do I go to the router login page?

Comment: Depends on the router model and/or the ISP. Please add more detail to your question.

Comment: The router is a TP-LINK TL-WR1043ND. What details would you like about the ISP? Not sure if the name is relevant

Comment: As those which might... That is router model and isp (including country)

Comment: Many routers have admin access over wifi disabled, to prevent fly-by attacks. You may need to access the same IP address over wired ethernet.

Comment: I think you're right in this case @Tetsujin. I'll find an Ethernet cable and check it out

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [TP-Link FAQ](https://www.tp-link.com/uk/support/faq/776/) you can access the router control panel by looking at the label underneath the router.

I understand you have put the routers IP address in, is it the same IP as the network gateway? You can try some common IP addresses: `192.168.0.1` `192.168.1.1` `192.168.0.254` and see if that works.

Also, make sure you're on your network proper and not a guest WIFI.